# Importlib not able to find the module while using jenkins however it runs fine when I run the code locally on my machine

Tags: python, jenkins

I am writing a piece of code where I am using importlib to get the list of functions defined in my python files (login.py/logout.py).

Here is my code directory structure:

```
project1
       |-- src
             |-- login.py
             |-- logout.py
       |-- core
             |-- sample.py
```

Here is the code of sample.py

```
 import importlib

 module = 'login'
 obj = importlib.import_module(module)
 print dir(obj)
```

When I execute the code locally from pycharm using python core/sample.py, I get the desired output. (please note that I have marked src and core as 'add as source root' in pycharm)

However I tried to run the code using Jenkins (by doing 'cd core && python sample.py' in the shell for Jenkins but I got following error:

```
File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project1/core/sample.py", line 2, in sample
obj = importlib.import_module(module)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named login
```

please note that I have already added the workspace for python by doing:

```
sys.path.append(os.environ['WORKSPACE'])
```

I tried to add folder 'src' also via sys.path.append('/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project1/src') but that also couldn't solve the issue

Please help!

Thanks in advance!